# What is $\tan^{-1}(x) - \tan^{-1}\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)$?

Tags: trigonometry

From the question that I'm trying to solve, going backwards it seems that the answer should be $\tan^{-1}\frac{x-\frac{1}{x}}{2}$, but I have don't know how to show this is true.

Edit: One way this question is relevant is when looking at the effect of different components of a transfer function in determining the phase of the plant at a particular frequency. It is often useful to formulate this in terms of the phase of individual sections of the transfer function of the plant and then looking at the overall effect. That's how I came across this problem as I was trying to write the expression for the phase of a system with a particular transfer function in a simplified way to draw some insights. The answers have been very helpful as I can now see that these problems in general can be simplified by using the tan double angle formula.

Comment: Hint: set equal to $y$, then use double angle formulae.

Comment: Interesting to see the old notation still being used : Since 2009, the ISO 80000-2 standard has specified solely the "arc" prefix for the inverse functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#arctan

Comment: @MartinHansen: If ISO thinks they can tell mathematicians what to do, they're pretty deluded. Especially since letting ISO tell you what to do means _paying (through the nose) for the privilege_ of getting to know what it is they're trying to tell you to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using
$$\tan{(A-B)}=\frac{\tan{(A)}-\tan{(B)}}{1+\tan{(A)}\tan{(B)}}$$
we have that
$$\tan{(\arctan{(x)}-\arctan{(\frac1x)})}=\frac{x-\frac1x}{1+x(\frac1x)}=\frac{x-\frac1x}{2}$$
So the given expression is
$$\arctan{(x)}-\arctan{(\frac1x)}=\arctan{(\frac{x-\frac1x}{2})}$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\theta = \tan^{-1} x$ and draw a triangle that shows this.  That is, $\tan \theta = x$, so let the opposite leg be $x$ and the adjacent leg be $1$.

What angel is $\phi = \tan^{-1}(1/x)$?  You have $\tan \phi = 1/x$, so $\phi$ must be the complementary angle to $\theta.$  So $$\tan^{-1} x +\tan^{-1}(1/x)=\theta+\phi = \pi/2.$$

Edit:  Well, I read the problem with a plus instead of a minus.  I'll leave this up for a while, because I think this is the right way to analyze such things.

Comment: Note that with a minus sign, you immediately deduce the form shown by E.H.E. from yours.

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan (\tan^{-1}(x) - \tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}))= {x-{1\over x}\over 1+x{1\over x}} ={x-{1\over x}\over 2}$$

So the answer is $$\tan^{-1}({x^2-1\over 2x})$$

Answer (score 1):

you can get another form
$$(\arctan{(x)}-\arctan{(\frac1x)})'=\frac{2}{1+x^2}$$
integrate $\frac{2}{1+x^2}$ to get
$$\arctan{(x)}-\arctan{(\frac1x)}=2\arctan x-\frac{\pi}{2} ..............x>0$$

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$
f(x)=\arctan x-\arctan\frac{1}{x}
$$
is defined for $x\ne0$. The derivative is
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{x^2}}\frac{-1}{x^2}=\frac{2}{1+x^2}
$$
Hence we can say that there exists constants $c_+$ and $c_-$ such that
$$
\arctan x-\arctan\frac{1}{x}=
\begin{cases}
c_++2\arctan x & x>0 \\[4px]
c_-+2\arctan x & x<0
\end{cases}
$$
Evaluating at $1$ yields $f(1)=0$, so $c_+=-\pi/2$; evaluating at $-1$ yields $f(-1)=0$, so $c_-=\pi/2$.

Thus
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2\arctan x-\dfrac{\pi}{2} & x>0 \\[4px]
2\arctan x+\dfrac{\pi}{2} & x<0 
\end{cases}
$$